# $set slowing down performance in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, set, v-for

Below is my code

```
    <div v-for="namespace in chosenNamespaces" v-bind:key="namespace.id">

<!--            Select the Parameter-->

    <select @change="updateParameter($event, namespace.id)" v-model="currParameterValues[namespace.id]">
        <option v-for="parameter in getParametersForNamespace(namespace.id)">{{parameter}}</option>
    </select>

<!--            Select Property -->

    <select @change="updatePropertyType($event, namespace.id)" v-model="currPropertyValues[namespace.id]">
        <option v-for="property in getPropertiesForNamespace(namespace.id)">{{property}}</option>
    </select>

    <!--            Select Item -->
    <select v-model="currItemValues[namespace.id]">
        <option v-for="item in getItemsForNamespace(namespace.id)">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>


methods: {
    updateParameter(data, id){
        ....
        this.$set(currParameterValues, id, data,target.value)
        this.$set(currPropertyValues, id, someValue)
    }

    updatePropertyType(data, id){
        ...
        this.$set(currPropertyValues, someThing, val)
    }
}
```

So I have many div which loops over the list of `chosenNamespaces` array and creates a set of selects. Now In that, I want to change the value of the second select i.e `Select for Property` when I change the value of `Select paramater` for that corresponding namespace using `updateParameter` method. I do that by using $set to update the array `currPropertyValues`. But I observe whenever I change the parameter option it take a while(4-5 secs) to process since maybe Vue takes time to react to the change in property array value. If I simply remove $set `updateParameter` it responds immediately.  How can I solve this?

**Edit**
Here I have replicated on fiddle, when I change a value in dropdown it takes time to reflect: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohdgadi/gxhn3em2/1/)

Comment: How many options are in your selects and what do `getParametersForNamespace` and `getItemsForNamespace` look like?  Maybe the options have to slowly re-render on every change.

Comment: Well, the selects only have 2-3 options at the moment. And the above functions just filter out an array of 6 elements by `namespace.id` and return the results. @Dan

Comment: I see, so there is no array bigger than 6?  And when you say "I have many div", how many?  What happens if you try with less?  Can you reproduce this behavior in a [fiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Dan Added a fiddle link in question edit

Comment: Thanks to the fiddle, I can see what went wrong.  I created an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of using the `v-model` array indexes like object keys, which creates huge arrays.  For example, doing the following creates an array with 152,395,893 items, which will be very slow to work with in a template:

```
const arr = [];
arr[152395893] = '...';
```

With an array, this number is not a key's name, but a numerical index.  What you want is an object.  This creates just 1 item:

```
const obj = {};
obj[152395893] = '...';
```

Change these both to objects:

```
currParameterValues: {},
currOperatorValues: {}
```

The [adjusted Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/wrx10gou/)

Comment: I owe you a cookie